# tar throws error when extracting file

Tags: tar

```
[root@localhost src]# tar -zxvf /root/Desktop/daq-2.0.4.tar.qz
tar (child): /root/Desktop/daq-2.0.4.tar.qz: Cannot open: No such file or directory
tar (child): Error is not recoverable: exiting now
tar: Child returned status 2
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
```

When I run that command, I get the error that it cannot open the file. I don't know why. Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

daq-2.0.4.tar.qz is not the name of the file that you downloaded, it is [daq-2.0.4.tar.gz](https://osdn.net/projects/sfnet_slackbuildsdirectlinks/downloads/daq/daq-2.0.4.tar.gz/) with a .gz extension, so the command `tar -zxvf /root/Desktop/daq-2.0.4.tar.qz` can't find it.

Change directories using `cd` to the directory containing daq-2.0.4.tar.gz and run this command:

```
tar -zxvf daq-2.0.4.tar.gz
```

I downloaded daq-2.0.4.tar.gz from the above link to my desktop and extracted it with the above command and it worked. Results:

```
daq-2.0.4/
daq-2.0.4/os-daq-modules/
daq-2.0.4/os-daq-modules/daq-modules-config.in
daq-2.0.4/os-daq-modules/daq_nfq.c
daq-2.0.4/os-daq-modules/daq_netmap.c
daq-2.0.4/os-daq-modules/daq_dump.c
daq-2.0.4/os-daq-modules/daq_static_modules.h
daq-2.0.4/os-daq-modules/Makefile.in
daq-2.0.4/os-daq-modules/daq_ipq.c
daq-2.0.4/os-daq-modules/daq_ipfw.c
daq-2.0.4/os-daq-modules/daq_pcap.c
daq-2.0.4/os-daq-modules/daq_static_modules.c
daq-2.0.4/os-daq-modules/daq_afpacket.c
daq-2.0.4/os-daq-modules/Makefile.am
daq-2.0.4/api/
daq-2.0.4/api/daq.h
daq-2.0.4/api/daq_mod_ops.c
daq-2.0.4/api/daq_api.h
daq-2.0.4/api/daq_common.h
daq-2.0.4/api/daq_base.c
daq-2.0.4/api/Makefile.in
daq-2.0.4/api/Makefile.am
daq-2.0.4/COPYING
daq-2.0.4/README
daq-2.0.4/sfbpf/
daq-2.0.4/sfbpf/win32-stdinc.h
daq-2.0.4/sfbpf/sf_gencode.c
daq-2.0.4/sfbpf/sfbpf-int.c
daq-2.0.4/sfbpf/ipnet.h
daq-2.0.4/sfbpf/sfbpf-int.h
daq-2.0.4/sfbpf/IP6_misc.h
daq-2.0.4/sfbpf/sfbpf.h
daq-2.0.4/sfbpf/nlpid.h
daq-2.0.4/sfbpf/sf-redefines.h
daq-2.0.4/sfbpf/grammar.y
daq-2.0.4/sfbpf/ethertype.h
daq-2.0.4/sfbpf/ieee80211.h
daq-2.0.4/sfbpf/sf_optimize.c
daq-2.0.4/sfbpf/arcnet.h
daq-2.0.4/sfbpf/ppp.h
daq-2.0.4/sfbpf/sfbpf_dlt.h
daq-2.0.4/sfbpf/llc.h
daq-2.0.4/sfbpf/scanner.l
daq-2.0.4/sfbpf/Makefile.in
daq-2.0.4/sfbpf/sll.h
daq-2.0.4/sfbpf/sunatmpos.h
daq-2.0.4/sfbpf/sf_bpf_printer.c
daq-2.0.4/sfbpf/sf_nametoaddr.c
daq-2.0.4/sfbpf/runlex.sh
daq-2.0.4/sfbpf/namedb.h
daq-2.0.4/sfbpf/sf_bpf_filter.c
daq-2.0.4/sfbpf/gencode.h
daq-2.0.4/sfbpf/bittypes.h
daq-2.0.4/sfbpf/atmuni31.h
daq-2.0.4/sfbpf/Makefile.am
daq-2.0.4/config.sub
daq-2.0.4/daq.dsp
daq-2.0.4/configure
daq-2.0.4/ChangeLog
daq-2.0.4/ltmain.sh
daq-2.0.4/install-sh
daq-2.0.4/config.h.in
daq-2.0.4/aclocal.m4
daq-2.0.4/depcomp
daq-2.0.4/Makefile.in
daq-2.0.4/m4/
daq-2.0.4/m4/ltoptions.m4
daq-2.0.4/m4/ax_cflags_gcc_option.m4
daq-2.0.4/m4/libtool.m4
daq-2.0.4/m4/lt~obsolete.m4
daq-2.0.4/m4/ltversion.m4
daq-2.0.4/m4/ltsugar.m4
daq-2.0.4/m4/sf.m4
daq-2.0.4/configure.ac
daq-2.0.4/config.guess
daq-2.0.4/missing
daq-2.0.4/Makefile.am
```

Comment: [root@localhost src]# tar -zxvf /root/Desktop/daq-2.0.4.tar.gz
tar (child): /root/Desktop/daq-2.0.4.tar.gz: Cannot open: No such file or directory
tar (child): Error is not recoverable: exiting now
tar: Child returned status 2
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
it's no working

Comment: I edited my answer.

Comment: it's still not working. it can't open: no such file or directory

Comment: i download from that link too. but it's not working with me. maybe i'll try close all table and start again. maybe it's work. i use these on centos 6.9

Comment: @CyrusPhạm CentOS is off topic here for obvious reasons. That said, you need to **run the above command in the same directory where you saved the file**.